# How to check for null values before doing .AddDays() in SSRS?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have the following as the value for my textbox in SSRS report:

```
   =iif(IsNothing(Fields!MyDate.Value), "", Format(Fields!MyDate.Value.AddDays(30), "MMMM dd, yyyy"))
```

It gives me an "#Error" every time MyDate is null.

How do i work around this?

UPDATE:

i wrote this custom function, it got rid of the error, but returns January 31, 0001 when null date is passed.

```
Public Shared Function NewDate(myDate as DateTime, days as integer) AS string
IF ISNOTHING(myDate) OR ISDBNULL(myDate) Then
    NewDate = "        "
ELSE
    NewDate = Format(myDate.AddDays(days), "MMMM dd, yyyy")
END IF
End Function
```

@Matt Hamilton: DateAdd("d", 30,Fields!MyDate.Value)

Comment: Why does it have to be inline?

Comment: Cuz up until 10 minutes ago i didn't know about "Custom Code" in SSRS :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem, of course, is that VB's IIF statement evaluates both sides regardless of the outcome. So even if your field is null it's still evaluating the "Value.DateAdd" call.

If I recall correctly, SSRS has its own "DateAdd" function that you can use instead. So you can do something like this (check the documentation 'coz this is from memory):

```
=Iif(IsNothing(Fields!MyDate.Value), "", Format(DateAdd("d", 30, Fields!MyDate.Value), "MMMM dd, yyyy"))
```

Comment: switch the parameters in the function, 30 should be #2

thanx